# When use my custom loss function I get this error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a custom loss function for my CNN but when I compile the model I get this error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'.
I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  y_pred = tf.keras.backend.get_value(y_pred)
  y_true = tf.keras.backend.get_value(y_true)
  errors = []
  for x in range(0,y_pred.shape[0]):
    error = 0
    true_range = np.argmax(y_true[x])
    for i in range(0, y_pred[x].shape[0]):
      error = error + ((i-true_range)**2)*y_pred[x][i]
    errors.append(error)
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(errors))

model.compile(loss = custom_loss, metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at the start of your program. This will add the support for numpy.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27519

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fix it with: `model.run_eagerly = True`. But now when call `model.fit(...)` I have this new error `No gradients provided for any variable`